# Use same inventory for multiple sites in django python

Tags: python, django, inventory

Hi is there a way that i can use a **same** **inventory** for **multiple** **sites** in **django**. I am using the cartridge in django with mezanine.I need to create a multisite project with single cartridge.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/multi-db/) with router:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
    },
    'cartridge': {
        'NAME': 'cartridge_data',
         ...
    }
}

class CartridgeRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'cartridge':
            return 'cartridge'
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'cartridge':
            return 'cartridge'
        return 'default'
```