# Saving models in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, multiple-sites

I am working on a ***multisite project*** and i am using **mezzanine+cartridge** for this. I want to use *same inventory for both sites*. But there are some issues with this: there is a field `site_id` in the `product` table which stores the ID of the current site. Thus, I cannot reuse `product` over sites.

Is there any way (like with the help of signals or anything) that I can save an entry twice in the database, with changes to some field's values?

If this is possible then I have to overwrite only `site_id`: the rest of the things remain the same as it was in the previous entry. Thereby it decreases the workload of entering products twice for different sites.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313538/use-same-inventory-for-multiple-sites-in-django-python/14317874#14317874) will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would caution against writing the same thing twice. Some thing will definitely go wrong, and you will have two nonmatching db's. Why don't you make the site_id-product relationship M2M, so that you can have more than one `site_id`'s?